# how to add a round border to a jradiobutton

Tags: java, swing, border, rounding, jradiobutton

Hi I need to add a Round Border, that could be etched, beveled etc.
for a JRadioButton.
to allow the button to keep its round appearance.

but i cannot find any round borders.

does anyone know how to do this?
chis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the [`Border`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/border/Border.html) interface, using [`drawRoundRect()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) or [`drawOval()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) in `paintBorder()`.

Comment: and, of course, set the border to the radio button: `radioButton.setBorder(new Border() {...});`

Answer (score 1):

thanks thats one option, but im trying not to add my own implementation, as that would then limit reusability of the software by others.

i currently had 
JRadioButton.setBorder(new EchtedBorder(..));
JRadioBUtton.setBorderPainted(true); //to make it actually be drawn for the radiobutton.

but it then appears square, with the default radiobutton (thats round) inside.

I wondered if there was ay way to get the radiobutton to obay its natural roundness?

Comment: You'd have to implement your own `BasicRadioButtonUI`; `MetalRadioButtonUI` is an example.

Comment: other option is to use images, which is what i think we did in the end.